# Libxml parser iphone issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using libxml for parsing the xml. I have referred  the XMLPerformance example by apple.
Following is the part of xml document which is causing a problem as it contain the "&nbsp" string. i cannot just replace this "&nbsp" with any other string is i am getting  data in didReceiveData delegate method and i am parsing that data.
Is there any solution to resolve this issue which is coming because of special character?

```
<ParentTag>
<AUTHOR>Actavis"Totowa&nbsp;"LLC</AUTHOR>
<SPL_INACTIVE_ING>lactose"monohydrate"/"magnesium"stearate"/"starch"pregelatinized"/"talc</SPL_INACTIVE_ING>
</ParentTag>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whats the output that libxml is giving you?

Comment: *** Assertion failure in errorEncounteredSAX()
this is the error libxml is giving.

Comment: Are you creating the html version, not the xml version?

Comment: I am getting this result from web service,i cannot change the server side.
it is the xml only but there are some tags which contain these special characters like "&nbsp".

Comment: Can u show us the code where you try to insert this value to your variable...

Comment: Following is the link of project which I have created for test.
LibXMLParser.m->downloadAndParse-> in this function i am fetching local xml.
In actual scenario i will get the data in 
ConnectiondidReceiveData method.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10999691/XMLPerformance.zip

Answer (score 0):

> To make sure your XML is well format, you can test you XML first with any online XML validator and then later you should parse that.